# How to redraw UITableViewCells automatically given different sorting parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController called HighScoreViewController that possesses UITableViewCells that are each individual HighScore objects.

When I press the segmented control at the top I want to resort the TableCells immediately. However, currently my sort only works by dragging around so that the cells are off-screen causing the `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to be called again (which resorts the individual cell according to the score, duration, or date).

I tried to create a method that would be called in my segmented control action that would remove and add the View to redraw the cells. When that didn't work I tried redrawing each cell manually but I realized that it would be a extremely complicated as I would have to monitor which scores had already been sorted in the View and what scores were sorted in the Data Source. I also tried `setNeedsDisplay`.

How can I resort the UITableViewCells immediately after pressing the segmented control?

[image: HighScoreVC]
[image: HSVCduration]

This is my action outlet for the segmented Control

```
- (IBAction)changeSort:(id)sender {


NSLog(@"changing Sort");
// Sorted by score
if (self.sortingButton.selectedSegmentIndex == SORT_BY_SCORE){
    [self sortHighScoresByScore];
}else if (self.sortingButton.selectedSegmentIndex == SORT_BY_DURATION){// sorted by duration
    [self sortHighScoresByDuration];
}else if (self.sortingButton.selectedSegmentIndex == SORT_BY_DATE){// sorted by last time played
    [self sortHighScoresByDate];
}else{
    NSLog(@"HighScoreViewController, changeSort else != 0,1,2");
}
}
```

And this is my cell method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HighScoreCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"inside TableView");

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"HighScoreCell"];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *playingCardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:@"playingCardHighScores"];
NSMutableArray *setCardHighScores = [defaults objectForKey:@"setCardHighScores"];

// Decode High Scores arrays
playingCardHighScores = [self decodeEncodedArray:playingCardHighScores];
setCardHighScores = [self decodeEncodedArray:setCardHighScores];

/* Will need to set the left and right side to two different scores or add some kind of slider*/
HighScore *hs = playingCardHighScores[indexPath.row];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 4, 260, 20)];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
label.tag=25;

UILabel *detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 260, 15)];
detailLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
detailLabel.tag=30;

NSString *score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%ld",(long)hs.score];
NSString *duration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@",Duration:%.2f",hs.secondsPlayed];
NSString *datePlayed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@",datePlayed:%@",hs.datePlayed];
NSString *combination = [score stringByAppendingString:[duration stringByAppendingString:datePlayed]];
detailLabel.text = combination;

[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];

// Should change depending on what selector is picked
NSString *strScore;
NSDate *date;
switch (self.sortingButton.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case SORT_BY_SCORE:
        strScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %ld",(long)hs.score];
        break;
    case SORT_BY_DURATION:
        strScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duration: %.2f seconds",hs.secondsPlayed];
        break;
    case SORT_BY_DATE:
        date = hs.datePlayed;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
// if the string exists
if (strScore){
    cell.textLabel.text = strScore;
}else{
    cell.textLabel.text = [date description];
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in your segmented control IBAction to get all the cells on screen to be recreated.

Alternatively if you want to be able to specify stock animation, you can call `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` on your table view

Comment: Amazing, I tried to call previously `[self.view reloadData]` when I was trying out different things. That explains why that didn't work. Thanks now! it's working great